# Extracting lines from txt file with Python

Tags: python

I'm downloading mtDNA records off NCBI and trying to extract lines from them using Python. The lines I'm trying to extract either start with or contain certain keywords such as 'haplotype' and 'nationality' or 'locality'. I've tried the following code:

```
import re
infile = open('sequence.txt', 'r') #open in file 'infileName' to read
outfile = open('results.txt', 'a') #open out file 'outfileName' to write

for line in infile:
    if re.findall("(.*)haplogroup(.*)", line):
        outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write(infile.readline())

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The output here only contains the first line containing 'haplogroup' and for example not the following line from the infile:

```
                 /haplogroup="T2b20"
```

I've also tried the following:

```
keep_phrases = ["ACCESSION", "haplogroup"]

for line in infile:
    for phrase in keep_phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            outfile.write(line)
            outfile.write(infile.readline())
```

But this doesn't give me all of the lines containing ACCESSION and haplogroup.

`line.startswith` works but I can't use this for lines where the word is in the middle of the line.

Could anyone give me an example piece of code to print the following line to my output for containing 'locality':

```
/note="origin_locality:Wales"
```

Any other advice for how I can extract lines containing certain words is also appreciated.

Edit:

```
                 /haplogroup="L2a1l2a"
                 /note="ethnicity:Ashkenazic Jewish;
                 origin_locality:Poland: Warsaw; origin_coordinates:52.21 N
                 21.05 E"
                 /note="TAA stop codon is completed by the addition of 3' A
                 residues to the mRNA"
                 /note="codons recognized: UCN"
```

In this case, using Peter's code, the first three lines are written to the outfile but not the line containing `21.05 E"`. How can I make an exception for `/note="` and copy all of the lines until the second set of quotation marks, without copying the `/note` lines containing `/note="TAA` or `/note="codons`

edit2:

This is my current solution which is working for me.

```
stuff_to_write = []
multiline = False
with open('sequences.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if any(phrase in line for phrase in keep_phrases) or multiline:
            do_not_write = False
            if multiline and line.count('"') >= 1:
                multiline = False
            if 'note' in line:
                if any(phrase in line.split('note')[1] for phrase in remove_phrases):
                    do_not_write = True
                elif line.count('"') < 2:
                    multiline = True
            if not do_not_write:
                stuff_to_write.append(line)
```

Comment: For starters, use `with open()` for accessing the files, and it'd be helpful if you uploaded a bit of your text file so people can come up with working code :)

Comment: Why do you have the line `outfile.write(infile.readline())` right after `outfile.write(line)`? Are you trying to write out the next line after a match? calling `readline` while looping over the file is going to cause problems. I can't even run this in 2.7 without getting a `ValueError` on that line.

Comment: @Peter Why would I use 'with open()' for opening the file? I figured the two examples I gave were enough since the text file is just more of the same.

Comment: @EricAppelt I put in `outfile.write(infile.readline())` because it was in the answer for a similar question but your explanation makes sense. Thanks. :)

Comment: When you use `with open()`, it makes sure the file is closed no matter what happens, where as with your code, if it fails during the execution for whatever reason, the file won't be closed :P   Also because it's indented, you don't need to use `file.close()` so it looks a little neater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search a file for matching phrases and will write those lines to a new file assuming anything after `"note"` doesn't match anything in `remove_phrases`.

It will read the input line by line to check if anything matches the words in  `keep_phrases`, store all the values in a list, then write them to a new file on separate lines. Unless you need to write the new file line by line as the matches are found, it should be a lot faster this way since everything is written at the same time.

If you don't want it to be case sensitive, change the `any(phrase in line` to `any(phrase.lower() in line.lower()`.

```
keep_phrases = ["ACCESSION", "haplogroup", "locality"]
remove_phrases = ['codon', 'TAA']

stuff_to_write = []
with open('C:/a.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if any(phrase in line for phrase in keep_phrases):
            do_not_write = False
            if 'note' in line:
                if any(phrase in line.split('note')[1] for phrase in remove_phrases):
                    do_not_write = True
            if not do_not_write:
                stuff_to_write.append(line)

with open('C:/b.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\r\n'.join(stuff_to_write))
```

Comment: This worked! :) I need to include 'note' as one of the words but I want to exclude any lines where 'note' is followed by 'codon' or 'TAA' like these:

                     /note="TAA stop codon is completed by the addition of 3' A

                     /note="codons recognized: AGY"

I understand that I need to do some sort of compound statement to include these exceptions but I don't know where or how to put it in without breaking it.

Comment: `/note` is still giving me grief. I edited my original question and explained the problem. Can you help?

Comment: Hmm, it's a little hard to understand haha, are you wanting to keep what is contained within speech marks after `/note` as long as it's not followed by those two phrases? I'd probably do it similar to your second bit I guess, I did once try something similar before, but it didn't work so well :)